# XML Sitemap: space or %20 in <loc>?

Tags: xml, sitemap

I am building a sitemap, should i use %20 or " " to specify urls in the

```
  <loc>
  </loc>
```

tag?

Example:

```
<loc>http://www.example.com/i love spaces.html</loc>
```

or

```
<loc>http://www.example.com/i%20love%20spaces.html</loc>
```

Are both valid???

Comment: It is best to create an URL slug so that spaces are replaced by a hyphen.